# Why are relative divs not generating height?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a 2 column grids. In column 1, there will be multiple instances of one div. Inside the one div there are two divs positioned absolutely - a number and a description. For some reason when I have multiple divs, they stack ontop of one another, which is because the 'template' div has no height.

Why a height is not automatically generated by the content within that `div`?

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0;
  display: block;
}

.col1 {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.col2 {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.indicator {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #0f0;
  color: #454;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="col1">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="indicator">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="indicator">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="indicator">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="indicator">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    Col 2 content.
  </div>
</div>
```

​Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/techydude/UcFXX/1/

This is a very basic question, but I would rather understand the reasoning behind the issue without creating a work around by adding height.

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements do not affect the dimensions of their parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute positioning removes the element from the "flow", so as far as its parent is concerned, it's not really there and it isn't calculated as part of the parent's height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sean Redmond. Did I set this up incorrectly then / is there a better way I should have set this up?

Comment: The simple answers are to set the parent's size explicitly or use relative positioning instead of absolute. `position: relative` doesn't remove the element from the flow. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I use absolute positioning because if the indicator and text were relative, the text div would be pushed down because of the height from the indicator div.

Comment: But I guess I could put the text div first, push it left 20px then position the indicator div absolutely, top:0, and left:0

Comment: You can also give .text a negative `top` position. `top: -10px; left: 20px` would accomplish the same thing (or something similar) without changing the order.